# How to restrict browser tab message while using ng-idle

Tags: angularjs, browser, angularjs-directive, ng-idle

I used AngularJS ng-idle in my application. As a result 'your session has expired' message shows on the browser tab when I moved to any other tab. I need ng-idle but don't want to show that message. How can I restrict. please helpme

```
app.config(['KeepaliveProvider', 'IdleProvider', function(KeepaliveProvider, IdleProvider) {
          IdleProvider.idle(25);
          IdleProvider.timeout(25);
          KeepaliveProvider.interval(50);
        }]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You must add in your title idle-disabled="true".

For example:

```
<title idle-disabled="true">Title</title>
```

Or if you want to show different message you can do it in your controller:

```
Title.idleMessage('Blaba {{minutes}}:{{seconds}} blablabla');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `ng-idle v1.0.0` or higher there is a `TitleService` which includes a `TitleProvider`
with option to disable the default enabled title changes.

So in your snipeet, just include `TitleProvider.enabled(false)`

```
app.config(['KeepaliveProvider', 'IdleProvider', 'TitleProvider', function(KeepaliveProvider, IdleProvider, TitleProvider) {
          TitleProvider.enabled(false);
          IdleProvider.idle(25);
          IdleProvider.timeout(25);
          KeepaliveProvider.interval(50);
        }]);
```

If you need more customization please read https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle/wiki/Title

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is the recommended way to do it; the 'hacky' alternative is to modify `angular-idle.js`, find the 'Title' factory around line 340 and comment out one statement on line 363:

```
  value: function(val) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(val)) return $document[0].title;

    //$document[0].title = val; --comment this out
  },
```